# How to specify formatter settings when dealing directly with a JArray?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following C# code that parses a JSON array using the `JArray.Parse` function, from Newtonsoft. Once that JSON is parsed into the JArray, I need to join the elements in the array into a semi-colon delimited list - so I'm using `string.Join`. This code works, and creates the semi-colon delimited list, but I need to specify particular formatting settings. I need to format dates a particular way. I don't see how to apply custom formatter settings when dealing with this JArray, though. Any ideas?

```cs
var json = "[\"2010-03-01T00:00:00+00:00\", \"2010-01-01T00:00:00+00:00\"]";
var array = JArray.Parse(json);
var result2 = string.Join(", ", array);
        
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

And the output of this is `03/01/2010 00:00:00, 01/01/2010 00:00:00`.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/M77aut

Comment: You should not use `JArray` for that. There are very few instances where using those types directly is beneficial. Try `var dates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Date>>(json);` then `string.Join(", ", dates.Select(d => d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")));`

Comment: It's not always going to be an array of dates, though. That's why I'm using `JArray`. Does your example still apply in a way?

Comment: I still wouldn't use `JArray` for such a thing. It really depends on what the range of types in the array are and if it's heterogeneous or homogeneous. Like is it always going to be an array of dates or always going to be an array of numbers?